# About the $k$th moment of the sum of independent r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, moment-problem

It is known that
$$
E[\:\{\:(X+Y) - E(X+Y)\:\}^2\:] = E[\:\{\:X - E(X)\:\}^2\:] + 
E[\:\{Y - E(Y)\:\}^2\:]
$$
(that it is the variance of the sum is the sum of variances given that the r.v's are independent. But I have what I think it is an interesting question:

\begin{align*}
E[\:\{\:(X+Y) - E(X+Y)\:\}^n\:] = E[\:\{X - E(X)\:\}^n\:] + 
E[\:\{\:Y - E(Y)\:\}^n\:]
\end{align*}

is it true?

I think it is. However, I have not been able to prove it yet. Can someone give a hint or an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

**This is false.**

Take $X,Y$ independent, both mean $0$. Then you ask whether, for all $n\geq 0$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^n] = \mathbb{E}[X^n]+\mathbb{E}[Y^n]
$$
Clearly, this "feels" false, so let's try the simplest examples: $X,Y$ both uniform on $\{-1,1\}$ (i.e, Rademacher random variables), and $n=4$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X+Y)^4] = \mathbb{E}[X^4] + 4\mathbb{E}[X^3]\mathbb{E}[Y] + 6\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y^2] + 4\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y^3]  + \mathbb{E}[Y^4] = 8
$$
using independence, the fact that $X^{2k} = 1$ and $X^{2k+1} = X$, and the fact that both r.v.'s have mean zero.
 But obviously,
$$
\mathbb{E}[X^4] + \mathbb{E}[Y^4] = 2 \neq 8\,.
$$

---

*I used $n=4$ since, as you point out, it is true for $n=2$, and it happens to be true as well for $n=3$ for independent Rademacher r.v.'s, as one can check.*

Comment: The $n=3$ case is true for any independent random variables symmetric about $0$

Comment: @Henry fair, but that's a bit besides the point (symmetric is stronger than mean zero, for integrable r.v.'s).

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample! I'm having a lot of problems calculating $E[\bar{X}^3]$ assuming that we have the $1$, $2$ and $3$-moments of $X_1$.

Comment: @JuanCorredor What do you mean here? If $X$ is a Rademacher (uniform on $\{-1,1\}$, then $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$, $X^2=1$ always (since $(-1)^2=1^2=1$), and $X^3=X$, so $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\mathbb{E}[1]=1$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^3]=\mathbb{E}[X]=0$. Similarly, $X^4=1$, so $\mathbb{E}[X^4]=1$.

Comment: No for Rademacher but in general.

Comment: Now I am puzzled. The counter-example above shows that the conjecture is false. What are you trying to do -- check whether it's true for $n=3$ specifically?

Answer (score 0):

There are versions of moments for which this is true, called cumulants; both mean and variance are cumulants. More info: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant.